# node to traverse cannot be null exception in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been trying CRUD operation using spring and hibernate but get following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at com.kimaya.webpanel.dao.MenuDAOImpl.getMenu(MenuDAOImpl.java:51) ~[MenuDAOImpl.class:na]
    at com.kimaya.webpanel.dao.MenuDAOImpl.removeMenu(MenuDAOImpl.java:87) ~[MenuDAOImpl.class:na]
    at com.kimaya.webpanel.service.MenuServiceImpl.removeMenu(MenuServiceImpl.java:48) ~[MenuServiceImpl.class:na]
    at com.kimaya.webpanel.web.controller.MenuController.removeMenu(MenuController.java:70) ~[MenuController.class:na]
```

Here is my MenuDAOImpl class

```
package com.kimaya.webpanel.dao;


import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kimaya.webpanel.model.Menu;
import com.kimaya.webpanel.model.User;

@Repository("menuDAO")
public class MenuDAOImpl implements MenuDAO {

    protected static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MenuDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addMenu(Menu menu) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String parentmenu = menu.getMenuname();
        String menuname[] = menu.getMenuname().split(" ");
        int parentid = Integer.parseInt(menuname[0]);
        //Query q = session.createQuery("from "+Menu.class.getName()+" where menuname="+menu.getMenuname());
        menu.setParentid(parentid);
        String mname[] = parentmenu.split(",");
        menu.setMenuname(mname[1]);
        session.save(menu);
    }

    public Menu getMenu(Integer menuid) {
        Session session=null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Menu> menus = null;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from" + Menu.class.getName() + "where menuid="+menuid);
             menus = q.list();
             return menus.get(0);
        }
        catch(HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return menus.get(0);

    }

    public void updateMenu(Menu menu) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.update(menu);
    }



    public List<Menu> menuList(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        //Query q = session.createQuery("select g from " + Menu.class.getName() + " g");
        //List<Menu> menulist = q.list();

        List<Menu> menulist = session.createQuery("from "+Menu.class.getName()).list();

        return menulist;
    }

    public void removeMenu(Integer menuid) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(this.getMenu(menuid));
            transaction.commit();
        } catch(HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }   
    }

}
```

I can not able to understand why this exception comes and how to resolve it.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: How is it duplicate?

Comment: You should google `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!` there are lots for links with various causes, some of them should help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem,obviously with this

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from" + Menu.class.getName() + "where menuid="+menuid);
```

You miss spaces. And, please, use parameters. For an example, in most situations, a parametrized query has a better performance (and doesn't have SQL injections).

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Menu where menuid = :menuid");
q.setParameter("menuid", menuid);
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem occurred just because of syntax error.one example for this is shown below

If you are missing from clause then also found the same issues

Wrong Query-

```
String query=" user where lid=? and lmt=?";
```

Right Query-

```
String query="from user where lid=? and lmt=?";
```